# How to remove a node at a given position in a singly linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to create a function that removes a node when given an specific location. If the location is out of range then a message will be displayed other than that it should remove the node.

I have tried if/else statements, for loops, while loops. I know part of the function works since I have done some tests.I know when the location is at the head the node will be removed, but when any other location is given even if the node exists at that location it still displays the out of range message.

```
template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::removeAt(int location)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
    current = first;
    int counter;

    if (location < 0 || location >= count)
    {
        cout << "location out of range\n";
    }
    else if(location == 0)
    {
        first = first->link;
        if (first == NULL)
            last == NULL;
        delete current;
    }
    else 
    {
        counter = 0;
   
        while (counter != location - 1)
        {
            current = current->link;
            counter++;
        }

        trailCurrent = current->link;
        current->link = trailCurrent->link;
        delete current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of this not working?

Comment: @Chris I can explain one, I have to put the data in a text file which contains 5 nodes. The console asks me for a location and I put location 2, and well there is a node there, but my text file would not do anything when I select that and the console will just print "out of range" when its supposed to delete it

Comment: Have you looked for questions on List here? There are literally hundreds. Also similar to yours. Most common mistake : Not initializing head and current pointer to `nullptr`. Also you wouldn't need counter at all.

Comment: @Pepijin Kramer yes I have, but all ones that I find do not have the parameter of the location, they have a pointer.

Comment: The best advise I can give you start using a debugger and single step through your code and check where your assumptions start to differ from your expectations. Debugging is a skill you need to develop at some  point, better do it now when code is still not so big.

Comment: @Denisse _showing_ is better than _describing_.

Comment: im not sure how to show it here @Chris

Comment: Edit your question to include a `main` function with code that results in an error. It would also be helpful to see the rest of your class to determine how things like `first` are initialized.

Comment: `current->link = trailCurrent->link; delete current;` Look at these two statements carefully. Do you see anything strange? (Spoiler alert) You are destroying a node pointed to by `current`. Why do you need to change something in that node just before the node ceases to exist? What overall effect does it have?

Answer (score 0):

You have `last == NULL;` where you intended `last = NULL;`.

What is missing: `--count;`.

Also the algorithm could use *aliasing*, using the **address** of either `first` or a `link` field.

```
... checks on count ...
nodeType<Type>*& a = first;
while (location > 0) {
    --location;
    a = a->link;
}
nodeType<Type>* dead = a;
a = a->link;
delete dead;
... last update ...
```

In C style what happens is more clear:

```
nodeType<Type>** a = &first;
while (location > 0) {
    --location;
    a = &(*a)->link;
}
nodeType<Type>* dead = *a;
*a = (*a)->link;
delete dead;
```

BTW `last` typically could be an alias too.